# update database from excel placed in sharepath whenever there is any change in excel data or excel file are replaced in sharepath

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

1.i have Employee table in my database and record are inserted into this table from excel file placed in sharepath.
But i want to track if any change made in employee excel OR entire file is replaced in share path then only my DB should be recreated.

Note: if no changes found the the db should not recreated.

Comment: That sounds like a really bad design. Why not have the user(s) directly work with the database? Reloading the (entire?) Excel file every time it's updated (which would only be on save? as otherwise they'd be out of sync if they changed things and didn't save) would be awful for performance and if people are using the table, then the table can't be updated/recreated until they're done or you kill or their connection. This just sounds like a recipe for disaster I'm afraid.

Comment: yes it seems to be bad design. consider we got some excel file from other application that have username and email addresses. i want to process that excel file and store it in DB and send feedback mail to all users automatically.

Comment: So start writing some code. This isn't something that can be easily done via tsql as it has no real file-system functionality. Access to this file might also be an issue - something you need to consider. I suggest you start with basic documentation like [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed?view=netframework-4.7.2) and figure out what approach you want to use. Polling for changes might be doable from within sql server.